# JavaScript RegEx not match

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote a function to get the middle name from a para like this

For:

- `firstName = "Jan"`,
- `lastName = "Levinson"`,
- `para = "Jan Jan Jan Jan Jan Jan Levinson Levinson Levinson Levinson Levinson"`

The expected output should be `["Jan", "Levinson"]`.

My code is written as below:

```js
function middleName(firstName, lastName, para) {
   var regex = new RegExp(firstName+"\040?([A-Z][a-z]*)\040?"+lastName, "g");
   var matches = para.match(regex);
   var out = [];

   if(matches instanceof Array) {
      matches.forEach(element => {
         element = element.substring(0, element.length - lastName.length);
         element = element.substring(firstName.length, element.length);
         element = element.trim();
         out.push(element);
      });
   }
   return out;
}

console.log(middleName("Jan", "Levinson", "Jan Jan Jan Jan Jan Jan Levinson Levinson Levinson Levinson Levinson"))
```

And my result is only `["Jan"]`.  What should be the correct **regex** implementation and why?

Comment: So you want to take only the first repeating word of a series of repeating words? Or you want to take one word of a series of 6 words? What do you mean?

Comment: It's not clear why you're using that regex (to me), but in the  `foreach` loop you are overwriting your `element` parameter so only one value gets pushed.

Comment: Try to explain what the goal of your algorithm is and add some comments to your code, it's not clear what you want because there are a lot of ways to get the output that you specified

Comment: Yet another explain you algorithm, please :)

Comment: I want to get middle name, it is a word with a upercase + some lower case. Maybe have a space between first name - middle name - last name or not. I have tried with some other case, the function is correct, but not in this case. I think after matching Jan in Jan Jan Levison it can not match Levison in Jan Levison Levison. More detail [here] (https://app.codesignal.com/challenge/DBQa6cjuqHt3b6qTx)

Comment: @Julio I get all results has correct format first name_middle name_last name and save in matches array. Then I try to get middile name by cut off first name and last name in each result.

Comment: Could the middle name be equal to the last name? What should we return on this case: `Jan Levinson Levinson`? Levinson? Or 'nothing'?

Comment: Another conflict is first and middle name to be equal. Can you clarify what to do on those cases?

Answer (score 0):

I tried [the code challenge](https://app.codesignal.com/challenge/DBQa6cjuqHt3b6qTx) by myself and the test that this relates to does not clearly match the challenge's description. Anyway, the following code runs green (at least the unlocked tests).

```
function middleName(firstName, lastName, para) {
    var pattern = firstName + "\\s?([A-Z][a-z]*)\\s?(" + lastName + ")?\\s?" + lastName;
    var regex = new RegExp(pattern, "g");
    var match;
    var matches = [];
    while ((match = regex.exec(para)) !== null) {
        matches.push(match[1]);
        if (match[2] !== undefined) {
            matches.push(match[2]);
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```